# NodeJS parallel running function to fetch data from an REST API

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I have been working with a `Node.js` code where I make a call to an API. I get a paginated response of 50 objects at a time. In a query parameter I set an offset as 0, 50, 100 to keep fetching the more data. if the response has 50 objects I increase my offset query parameter. And once the data is less that 50 I stop the call. Is there any way I can split the calling to get data in a faster way? Suppose I call **api?offset=0**, **api?offset=50**, **api?offset=100**, **api?offset=150**, in parallel so that I get data in a faster way, and collect the data of all the calls made. Also if there is no data stop calling for the next offset values.
**NOTE**: I don't know the offset limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use recursive function

Since you don't know what the offset limit would be your best guess is to great groups of requests, so you will reach your offset faster.

For async tasks I love to use `async` [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map). Here is an example :

```js
const async = require('async')

const offsets = [0, 50, 100, 150];
async.map(offsets, function (offset, callback) {
  
  // Do request here with 'offset'
  // And return response in the callback
  // Do not return an error, otherwise the main callback (of map function)
  // will be called immediately
  return callback (null, response);

}, function (error, results) {

  // results is an array containing all responses from all requests
  // iterate over results, if all contain a valid result, 
  // you can increase your offset group and perform this operation again

});
```

Of course you will need to wrap this into another function which allows for an increasing offsetgroup , repeating the requests as long as you get valid results -> a so called **recursive function** :

```js
const async = require('async')

function performGroupRequest (offsets, allResults, end) {
  
  async.map(offsets, function (offset, callback) {
  
    // Do request here with 'offset' and return response in the callback
    return callback (null, response);

  }, function (error, results) {
  
    // check results
    results.map(r => {
      if (hasItems(r)) {
        // valid result, add to allResults
        allResults.push(r);
      } else {
        // invalid result, let's end here
        return end(allResults);
      }
    });

    // all results are valid here, so call the function again, with increased offset
    performGroupRequest(offsets.map(o => o + 200), allResults, end)

  });
}

function getAllItems () {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
    performGroupRequest([0, 50, 100, 150], [], function(all) {
      return resolve(all);
    });
  
  });
}

// start the journey

getAllItems().then((allResults) => {
});
```

Please note : I totally omitted error handling here for simplicity reasons.